# How does caching work when the data may have changed in WebApi

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api

I've got a fundamental mis-understanding on how caching works as everywhere I have read says it can help improve performance but I just can't for the life of me see how this might be the case in my situation.

I currently have a MVC.NET WebApi on Microsoft Azure that returns various bits of information to a client.  However the client wants to make sure they have the latest information so they don't really want stale data.  In saying that, the data doesn't always change so there's a chance that in general it will be the same between requests.

Would caching allow for calls to the WebApi be improved in regards to performance?  I don't see how I could enable caching as I then run the risk of giving old re-redundant data to the user.

Is caching only worthwhile when a site is being hit hundred's of times at once?

Answer (score 1):

It really does depend on several factors.

- As you say, how frequently the API is being called?
- What does the client consider stale-data?
- Can you tell that the data in the cache is out of date?
- Are you charged for
  CPU/ db usage which would be reduced if data retrieval was avoided?

There are way more I expect, but these are the ones that immediately come to mind.

If the API isn't being called very often it might not be worth caching the output.

For caching that I have done with regards to web api output, for example, the api has been serving data from XML files that are periodically updated by another system. In this case I can deserialize the file into a typed object and memory cache the object with a file change monitor which invalidates the cache item when the file changes.
See [HostFileChangeMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.hostfilechangemonitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [CacheItemPolicy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
I have only used HostFileChangeMonitor, but it looks like there are various other "change monitors", like [SqlChangeMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or you could probably create your own inheriting from ChangeMonitor.

If you can't use a change monitor, you can set the CacheItemPolicy to invalidate after an interval or at a time. Potentially even caching a result for a few seconds could significantly reduce the work your server has to do if the data is requested heavily.